# Getting POST data which is serialized

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, serialization

I have two separate files, one is `bargraph.html` and the other is `data.php`

A section of `bargraph.html` is as follows:

```
<form method="POST" name="dataform" action="">
  <select id="data1" name="data1" id="data1-value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="data2" name="data2" id ="data2-value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
   </select>
   <button type="button" id="submitButton" 
name="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitButton').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#dataform').serialize(),
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }, 
        complete: function(){
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

Part of `data.php` is as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['data1'])) { 
        $opp1 = $_POST['data1']; 
} else { 
        $opp1 = 'SystemID'; 
        }
if (isset($_POST['data2'])) { 
        $opp2 = $_POST['data2']; 
        } else { 
    $opp2 = 'ApparentPower'; 
                }

    $sql = "SELECT $opp1, $opp2 FROM RaritanMachineDataa";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); // execute select query from database
$data = array(); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row);
    $data[] = $row; //add results to data array
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result); //free result entry
sqlsrv_close($conn); // close connection
echo json_encode($data); //encode data to JSON
```

In my `bargraph.html` I have two drop down menus, I am trying to send the two options selected to my `data.php` file to perform a select query on my database.

When I run my code, and for example if I choose `InletCurrent` and `InletVoltage` from the two drop downs and hit submit, it returns a browser pop up:

[image]

`data.php` file still echos `SystemID` and `ApparantPower`. See here https://imgur.com/awKkuJv

I want the options selected from the drop down to send to data.php file and to perform a select query using the two options against my database.

Could I get some help on this please? Do I need to un-serialize the data in `data.php`? If so, how? I am unable to find an example online specific to my code layout

MySQL table structure: https://imgur.com/oUpDjSP

UPDATE: I have now changed my bargraph.html to the following:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e){

      var data1=$("#data1").val();
      var data2=$("#data2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success:function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                console.log('#dataform');
            }, 
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The above code now prints the the right data chosen from the drop downs into my `browser console`, however it does not update `data.php` when I run it. It is still showing `SystemID` and `ApparentPower` when I run `data.php`.

Comment: The data is sent in json format. You should not need to do anything, but you can check `var_dump($_POST)` to verify

Comment: @aynber - A small note, as far as I know, `.serialize()` creates a query string, not json or you would need to use the `php://input`-stream.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True, but the data shown in the popup is json, which is why I said that. Though that's probably coming from the database query, now that I really look at it.

Comment: I actually helped answer his question in a previous post. I supplied this link in a previous chat to how serializable works with this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp

Comment: @aynber - Ah. Y, I just assumed that was the response, even though I've learned that you never should assume anything here :-)

Comment: I think at this point he needs to check if `$_POST` is getting set to whichever values he selected in the dropdown by echoing them

Comment: @Danny, here is your fix answered by Vidal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serializing ,you can just pass value like this

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e){



      var data1=$("#data1").val();//getting value of dropdown 1
      var data2=$("#data2").val();//getting value of dropdown2

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},//passing values
            success:function(data){ 
                alert(data); 
            }, 
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: We already did that, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188991/discussion-between-kebab-programmer-and-danny. read this chat thread to see why he can't use that

Comment: @KebabProgrammer - If you've already discussed this with the OP on another of their posts, shouldn't this post then be a duplicate of that?

Comment: I forgot to tell OP to set the id of the form, silly me >.>

Comment: I just tried this, this is printing the correct data (data I choose from the drop down) into my browser console, however it is not inserting those values into my select query on the database?

Comment: What is your expected output? Also post your table structure or try using **where** clause also  in your query

Comment: @Swati The data selected should post to data.php file shown above and query the database using those values posted from bargraph.html. It is currently not doing that and is showing SystemID and ApparentPower when I run data.php in browser.

Comment: @Swati If I use WHERE in my select statement, this just outputs SystemID and ApparentPower onto data.php still and not the chosen data from the drop downs

Comment: Nothing wrong at your php side , i think you have 2 id’s for dropdown , that might be problem . Check here -> **<select id="data1" name="data1" id="data1-value">** try removing one from both drop-down then might it work !

Comment: @Swati How will I then grab the 2 separate options chosen by user?

Comment: You have 2 id attribute’s , i just said to remove one i.e **id="data1"** and **id=“data1-value”**

Comment: @Swati Oh yeah, just removed one of them from both and it is still not updating my data.php output. Browser console however does print the two chosen options in JSON format.. ?

Comment: Try checking what is send to server , open your network tab in chrome see there what request is send to php page

Comment: network tab says data.php is being set when I choose from the drop downs. Why is my data.php file not then updating when I load it via URL. It displays SystemID and ApparentPower and not my chosen options from drop down.

Comment: Clear **cache** and see once

Answer (score 1):

I think your are missing the id on the form, **dataForm**. You are selecting the form using **$('#dataForm').serialize()**, but you don't have an id on the form.

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

```
<form method="POST" name="dataform" action="" id='dataForm'>
  <select id="data1" name="data1" id="data1-value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="data2" name="data2" id ="data2-value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
   </select>
   <button type="button" id="submitButton" 
name="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitButton').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#dataform').serialize(),
        success:function(data){ 
           console.log('---Data submitted---');
           console.log($('#dataform').serialize());
           console.log('Returned Data: '+ data);
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log('Error:' + thrownError);

        }, 
        complete: function(){
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Good job man, I forgot to tell him to add the id to the form, because there was so much things I had to edit previously for his other question that that part slipped my mind :D

Comment: I glad I was able to help !

Comment: Yea, thanks dude, my head was getting fried badly, its why you need an extra extra pair of eyes. I upvoted for you :)

Comment: I just added id as above but same problem

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: Same exact problem in my original post. It is returning a browser popup still, see screenshot in my post.

Comment: you have an alert(data) on success, is the result you want showing on the alert box? or the alert that you are mention is the alert(thrownError)? also for better debugging you should use console.log(data) for example. can you more specific on the problem ?

Comment: Okay so when I choose any two options from the drop down menu, it prints in the console SystemID and ApparentPower in JSON format. It does not print the data I choose from the drop down menu.

Comment: Can you update your code with a full list of data.php

Comment: @KebabProgrammer I have added data.php code and a part of the output.

Comment: @KebabProgrammer could I get some help please? Can we chat?

Comment: @Danny what's up?

Comment: @KebabProgrammer Need some guidance, can we chat :) regarding my graph and drop down menu selection and mysql

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188991/discussion-between-kebab-programmer-and-danny

Comment: the chat room we use before

Answer (score 1):

Try with giving id to form.

```
<form method="POST" id="dataform" name="dataform" action="">
</form>
```

You have used "$('#dataform').serialize()" in ajax call but not assign id to form.